# replace values of an array within range

Tags: ruby

Given the following array.

```
arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...,10000]
```

How to efficiently replace values in a given range...

Expected output:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7...,10000]
```

probably like doing this or something, but this is not working well because instead of replacing, it deletes all the elements specified in the range and replaces with one element.

```
arr[8..100]=7
```

Comment: What do you mean with "this is not working well"? What exactly did you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) method.

```rb
array.fill(7, 8..100)
```

Comment: @Fernand Note that this answer fills the array from index `8` up to and including index `100` with the value `7`. It does not check if the array element is within the given range. It's not quite clear from the question if the range is supposed to be the index or the contents, since both are the same in the question.